# getting error in python in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

##[error]There was an error when attempting to execute the process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/bin/python'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/bin/python ENOENT

```
teps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.9'
      addToPath: true
      architecture: 'x64'
  - bash: 
     pip install wheel --upgrade
     pip install dohq-artifactory
     pip install hvac
     pip install -r /home/vsts/work/1/b2b-gsp-deltadevops/python-scripts/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
    displayName: Install Required Python Packages
```

```
''' Merger module '''
import sys

from modules.delta_builder import buildDelta, mergeDelta
from modules.git.utils import is_commit_user_configured, is_git_repository, is_valid_remote
from modules.utils import FATAL_LINE, SUCCESS_LINE, WARNING_LINE
from modules.utils.argparser import parseArgs
from modules.utils.exceptions import ( CommitUserNotConfigured, InvalidRemoteSpecified, MergerException, 
                                        MergerExceptionWarning, NotAGitRepository )

__version__ = "3.3.1"


def prevalidations(args):

    if not is_git_repository():
        raise NotAGitRepository(
```

Is there any python version issue pipeline above error what is the solution

why it is happening error when running the python task

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue with Python in Pipeline while pip installing packages.
Adding [Pip Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/pip-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipeline) task before `UsePythonVersion0` resolved in my case.